# Video not displaying after pagination

Tags: flutter, video-player, tiktok

`View`

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:expandable_text/expandable_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:flutx/flutx.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';
// import 'package:okok/application/views/live_testing_sidebar.dart';
import 'package:okok/application/controllers/live_controller.dart';
import 'package:okok/application/models/live_reels.dart';
import 'package:okok/application/data/app_constants.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class LiveScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LiveScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  LiveScreenState createState() => LiveScreenState();
}

class LiveScreenState extends State<LiveScreen> {
  late LiveController controller;
  late VideoPlayerController _videoController;
  late Future _initializeVideoPlayer;

  bool isFavorite = false;
  int snappedPageIndex = 0;
  bool _isPlaying = true;
  int paginationPage = 1;

  final PageController _pageController = PageController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = FxControllerStore.putOrFind(LiveController());

    // Attach a listener to the page controller to detect page changes
    _pageController.addListener(() {
      if (_pageController.page == _pageController.page!.toInt()) {
        int currentPage = _pageController.page!.toInt();
        int totalPages = controller.liveTemplate!.length;

        if (currentPage == totalPages - 1) {
          // User has reached the end of the last page, load more content
          paginationPage += 1;
          controller.loadMoreData(paginationPage);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FxBuilder(
      controller: controller,
      builder: (controller) {
        return _buildBody();
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    if (!controller.isReelFetched) {
      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
    } else {
      print("THE LENGTH OF liveTemplate: ${controller.liveTemplate!.length}");
      for (ReelTemplate reel in controller.liveTemplate!) {
        print("The URL is: $reel.url");
      }
      return Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("LIVE Page"),
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        body: PageView.builder(
          controller: _pageController,
          onPageChanged: (int page) => {
            setState(() {
              snappedPageIndex = page;
            }),
          },
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemCount: controller.liveTemplate!.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            // Create a new VideoPlayerController for each video
            final videoURL = "${controller.liveTemplate?[index].videoUrl}";
            final videoController = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(Uri.parse(
              'http://okok.spassolab.com/images/videos/$videoURL',
            ));

            // Initialize the video controller
            final initializeVideoPlayer = videoController.initialize();
            videoController.setLooping(true);
            videoController.play();

            // ignore: no_leading_underscores_for_local_identifiers
            void _pausePlayVideo() {
              (videoController.value.isPlaying)
                  ? videoController.pause()
                  : videoController.play();
            }

            return Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: FutureBuilder(
                    future: initializeVideoPlayer,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                        if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return Center(
                            child:
                                Text("ERORR LOADING VIDEO: ${snapshot.error}"),
                          );
                        } else {
                          return Center(
                            child: AspectRatio(
                              aspectRatio:
                                  9.0 / 19.0, // Set the aspect ratio directly
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () => _pausePlayVideo(),
                                child: Stack(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    VideoPlayer(videoController),
                                    // No need for VideoProgressIndicator in this case
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                      } else {
                        return Container(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Lottie.asset('assets/tiktok-loader.json',
                                width: 100, height: 100, fit: BoxFit.cover));
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                // Progress Indicator at the bottom
                Positioned(
                  left: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  bottom: 0,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    child: FutureBuilder(
                      future: initializeVideoPlayer,
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                          return VideoProgressIndicator(
                            videoController,
                            allowScrubbing: true,
                            colors: const VideoProgressColors(
                              playedColor: Colors.red,
                              bufferedColor: Colors.grey,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                            ),
                          );
                        } else {
                          // Show a loading indicator while initializing the video
                          return const Visibility(
                              visible: false,
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end, children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 3,
                    child: Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
                      child: _videoDetails(index),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
                      child: liveSideBar(index),
                    ),
                  ),
                ])
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  // this is to gather sidebar items
  Widget liveSideBar(int index) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          _profileImageButton(index),
          _sideBarItem(
              'heart', '${controller.liveTemplate?[index].numberOfFavorites}'),
          _sideBarShare(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  // The sidebar items function
  _sideBarItem(String iconName, String label) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.favorite,
            size: 36, // Set the icon size to make it bigger
            color: isFavorite ? Colors.red : Colors.white, // Toggle icon color
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              isFavorite = !isFavorite; // Toggle the favorite state
            });
          },
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 5,
        ),
        Text(
          label,
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16, // Set the font size
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, // Set the font weight
            color: Colors.white, // Set the text color
            // You can add more styling options here, such as fontFamily, letterSpacing, etc.
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  // The sidebar items function
  _sideBarShare() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.share, // Change to the share icon
            size: 36, // Set the icon size to make it bigger
            color: Colors.yellow, // You can set the icon color as you like
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            // Add the logic for sharing here
          },
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 5,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  // Profile picture in sidebar
  _profileImageButton(int index) {
    String imgURL = "${controller.liveTemplate?[index].userProfile}";
    return Stack(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage(
                  '$imageURL/$imgURL'), // Concatenate the base URL and image URL correctly
              fit: BoxFit.cover, // Adjust the fit as needed
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  // this is to gather video description
  Widget _videoDetails(int index) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
          child: Text(
            "@${controller.liveTemplate?[index].username}",
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 22, // Set the font size
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, // Set the font weight
              color: Colors.white, // Set the text color
              // You can add more styling options here, such as fontFamily, letterSpacing, etc.
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 12),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
          child: ExpandableText(
            '@${controller.liveTemplate?[index].videoDescription}',
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18, // Set the font size
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, // Set the font weight
              color: Colors.white, // Set the text color
              // You can add more styling options here, such as fontFamily, letterSpacing, etc.
            ),
            expandText: 'more...',
            collapseText: 'less',
            expandOnTextTap: true,
            collapseOnTextTap: true,
            maxLines: 2,
            linkColor: Colors.grey,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 36,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  // Video Screen
  Widget _videoTile(int index, int snappedIndex) {
    String videoURL = "${controller.liveTemplate?[index].videoUrl}";
    print("The video url is: $videoURL");
    _videoController = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(
        Uri.parse('http://okok.spassolab.com/images/videos/$videoURL'));

    // final chewieController = ChewieController(
    //   videoPlayerController: _videoController,
    //   autoInitialize: true,
    //   autoPlay: true,
    //   looping: true,
    //   allowMuting: false,
    //   errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {
    //     return Center(
    //       child: Text(errorMessage),
    //     );
    //   },
    // );

    _initializeVideoPlayer = _videoController.initialize();
    _videoController.setLooping(true);
    _videoController.play();

    // Determine the aspect ratio of the video
    double videoAspectRatio = _videoController.value.aspectRatio;

    // Check if the video is horizontal (landscape)
    bool isHorizontalVideo = videoAspectRatio >= 1.0;

    // ignore: no_leading_underscores_for_local_identifiers
    void _pausePlayVideo() {
      (_videoController.value.isPlaying)
          ? _videoController.pause()
          : _videoController.play();
    }

    // (snappedIndex == index && _isPlaying)
    //     ? _videoController.play()
    //     : _videoController.pause();
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _initializeVideoPlayer,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          double videoAspectRatio = _videoController.value.aspectRatio;

          return Center(
            child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: videoAspectRatio,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => _pausePlayVideo(),
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  children: [
                    VideoPlayer(_videoController),
                    // Wrap VideoProgressIndicator with a transparent background
                    Positioned(
                      left: 0,
                      right: 0,
                      bottom: 0,
                      child: Container(
                        color:
                            Colors.transparent, // Set a transparent background
                        child: VideoProgressIndicator(
                          _videoController,
                          allowScrubbing: true,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          // Show a loading indicator while initializing the video
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

`controller`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutx/flutx.dart';
import 'package:okok/application/live_reel_constants.dart';
import 'package:okok/application/models/live_reels.dart';

class LiveController extends FxController {
  late PageController pageController;
  bool isReelFetched = false;
  List<ReelTemplate>? liveTemplate = [];

  bool isVideoPlaying = true;
  bool isLoading = false;
  int currentPage = 1;
  int itemsPerPage = 5;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData(currentPage, itemsPerPage);
  }

  void getData(int currentP, int itemsPer) async {
    String currentPage = currentP.toString();
    String itemsPerPage = itemsPer.toString();
    try {
      print("GET DATA RUN");
      LiveCache.liveReels =
          await ReelTemplate.getLive(currentPage, itemsPerPage);
      // if (LiveCache.liveReels != null) {
      for (ReelTemplate reels in LiveCache.liveReels!) {
        liveTemplate?.add(reels);
      }
      // } else {
      // print("No data available.");
      // }
    } catch (e) {
      print("ERROR FETCHING DATA: $e");
    }
    isReelFetched = true;
    update();
  }

  void changeToPlay() {
    isVideoPlaying = true;
    update();
  }

  void changeToPause() {
    isVideoPlaying = false;
    update();
  }

  void changePlayingStatus() {
    if (isVideoPlaying = false) {
      isVideoPlaying = true;
    } else {
      isVideoPlaying = false;
    }
    update();
  }

  void loadMoreData(int page) async {
    String contentPage = page.toString();
    try {
      // Prevent multiple requests while loading
      if (isLoading) return;

      isLoading = true; // Set loading flag to true
      print("GET DATA RUN");
      final newItems = await ReelTemplate.getLive(contentPage, '5');
      // Check if there are new items
      if (newItems.isNotEmpty) {
        liveTemplate!.addAll(newItems);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("ERROR FETCHING DATA: $e");
    }
    isLoading = false; // Reset loading flag
    isReelFetched = true;
    update();
  }

  @override
  String getTag() {
    return 'LiveController';
  }
}
```

`model`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:okok/application/data/app_constants.dart';

class ReelTemplate {
  String username,
      videoDescription,
      numberOfFavorites,
      videoUrl,
      totalViewers,
      userProfile;

  ReelTemplate(this.username, this.videoDescription, this.numberOfFavorites,
      this.videoUrl, this.totalViewers, this.userProfile);

  static Future<List<ReelTemplate>> getLive(
      String page, String itemsPerPage) async {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = await getData(page, itemsPerPage);
    List<ReelTemplate> liveList = data
        .map((Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) => ReelTemplate(
            jsonData['member_name'],
            jsonData['deal_name'],
            jsonData['total_favourites'],
            jsonData['url'],
            jsonData['total_viewers'],
            jsonData['profile_picture']))
        .toList();
    return liveList;
  }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getData(
      String page, String itemsPerPage) async {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> responseDataList = [];
    final url = Uri.parse('${apiURL}get-live.php');
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = {
      'page': page,
      'itemsPerPage': itemsPerPage,
    };
    final response = await http.post(url, body: data);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final decodedResponse = json.decode(response.body);

      if (decodedResponse['err'] == '000') {
        if (decodedResponse['return'] != null &&
            decodedResponse['return'] is List) {
          responseDataList =
              List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(decodedResponse['return']);
        } else {
          print('Invalid response format: result is not a list');
        }
      } else {
        print('Unknown error code: ${decodedResponse['err']}');
      }
    } else {
      print('Failed to fetch data: ${response.statusCode}');
    }
    return responseDataList;
  }
}
```

The code above, I am creating a tiktok similar video page. I was able to display the video taken from database at first, but when i tried to achieve pagination to pull more data from database, it shows

`error`
platformexception(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackExceptiom: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index =0, format=Format(1, null, null, video, avc, avc1.64001E, 01, null, [338, 640, 25.0], [-1, -1]), format_supported=YES, null, null)